# How to convert NSData into image (Mat) of OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

The app receives bytes which are the **image data (PNG format)**.
How to convert `NSData` bytes or (const void *) buffer into cv::Mat?
I know I have to use something like

```
NSData -> some array -> imdecode -> cv::Mat
```

How to do this in proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be it will help for the other generations.
The solution:

```
NSData *data = ....//some byte array data
cv::Mat matC = cv::imdecode(Mat(1, (int)[data length], CV_8UC1, (void*)data.bytes), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

Comment: Hi When i change my nsdata to mat the size of the image increase from 2mb to 18mb do you have any idea when it can come frome